# Best practice when automating Drupal (or other soft) installation regarding database settings

Tags: automation, drupal

Suppose I have Drupal and CiviCRM installations to automate.

These, however, need particular configs for working together (some file edits and database configs)

Should I make a fixed version install (eg. [Drupal 4.7.5](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/4.7.5) + CiviCRM 4.5.6), install them and configure, and then save the edited files plus database?

Or should I put more effort in my build script and make some queries and seds to edit those configs in the database and files?

Comment: Drupal ***4.7.5*** ... really? That's a release from Jan 5, 2007 ... Are you familiar with what (the scary) [Drupal 7.32](https://www.drupal.org/drupal-7.32-release-notes) was all about?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens sorry, I didnt check versions, were just example numbers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question sounds like you should have a look at what I call **F**eatures **C**onfiguration **M**anagement, aka **FCM**. FCM is not only about using Drupal's [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) module, and not about ***Configuration Management*** (as introduced in Drupal version 8). Instead, it is a special case of [**S**oftware **C**onfiguration **M**anagement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_configuration_management), aka **SCM**, applied to Drupal.

Mostly because [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) can be considered as a code generator, whereas that generated code may be considered as the *build script* (as in your question). Which can then also be used to be migrated through multiple environments.

Have a look at my (popular) answer to "[How to use the Features module in a 3 dev environments?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/199860/39516)" for (way) more details about all this.